# Problem storing a 2D array in a file and then loading it C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I'm trying to save a 2D string array in a file and trying to load it up again like when i reopen my program it should automatically assign the last input values. I'm having some trouble and I hope someone can look at my problem and help me with it as I'm just a beginner in C++.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


//String Array To Store These boxes [ ] as values.

string arr[4][4]={{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"},{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"},{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"},{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"}};
void Save();
void Load();
fstream fin;
main()
{
    Load();
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Enter Value for A4: ";
    cin>>arr[0][3];
    Save();
    getchar();
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    getchar();
}

// Function to Save New Value In A File

void Save()
{
    fin.open("New.txt",fstream::out);
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        {
            fin<<arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    fin.close();
}

// Function To Load Saved Values From The File Into Array arr

void Load()
{
    fin.open("New.txt",fstream::in);
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
        {
            fin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

So, it runs perfectly the first time as I know it's a working code:

[image]

But when I reopen the program it messes up the matrix:

[image]

What I want to do is to store the values for array elements by asking user to input the it can only be [X] I have it figured it in another main program and then I want to load the values from a file when I reopen the program. I'm only asking input for arr[0][3] right now because I'm just trying to figure the main idea of loading up my array and I'm calling it A4 because of the first row and 4th column.

Comment: Remember that `>>` skips whitespace.

Comment: Consider making `fin` local to `Save` and `Load`. `Load` doesn't close `fin` and this will cause problems with `Save` later. If it's local, those problems go away. `main` needs to return `int`.

Comment: nope still not working @user4581301 is there any way to not skip whitespaces?

Comment: Look at the output file and ask yourself "How is C++ supposed to distinguish one string  from the next?" Come up with a good solution to that and you're on your way.

Comment: thank you did a little more digging into my code and output file and now I have it done!

Comment: You will either need to put delimiters between the strings in your file or read only a fixed number of characters with `getline`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The operator>> eats whitespace (space, tab, newline). 
In order to distinguish 1 string from another in your file, you need to have appropriate delimiter.